# Efficient Collision Detection With Numerous Objects at Once

Tags: c++, sdl, detection

I am developing a 2D game with very large levels in which two teams(around 200 objects per team) fight against each other in planes, tanks, turrets,...etc. With every entity shooting bullets at their enemy it is expected that there would be a numerous amount of objects at one instant. What collision detection algorithm could I use to support collision for a massive number of entities? The objects are simple figures(rectangles and circles). Would a brute force approach suffice or break up the level into a grid?

Comment: You can use a pool for the bullets, to not allocate memory every time you shoot, also for collision you can use and API to do that, or you wanna make it "by hand"?

Comment: why not use physics engine like box2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use brute force approach. You will very soon get into troubles with performance. There's plenty of papers and articles about this topic.

But unless you really want to implement your own solution, pick an existing collision/physics engine that can resolve this for you. You are making a 2D game, then the obvious choice is [Box2D](http://box2d.org/), which is ported to many platforms and used in many game engines and games (e.g. Angry Birds and  its clones). Also this question is probably better suited for [Game Development site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) as you are not really solving any specific programming problem.